# HTML - ruby form action and URL redirection issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, forms, post, html-email

I am using rails at the back end and html for in the front end with angular js.

I have an HTML email and this form is present inside the email. I want the user to input his contact and submit the form. Upon submitting, I want him to go to a `/beta` page.

I have defined a controller for the route `https://example.com/wait/number`. The controller gets the form data, saves the value and redirects to the /beta page. On the browser, the beta page is rendered but the URL is still `https://example.com/wait/number`.

I do not know how to solve this problem. Tried lot of times but not proceeding.

Please let me know if you need any more data from my side.

```
<form method="post" action="example.com/wait/number">

    <input type="text" id="phone_number" name="phone_number"/> 

    <input type="hidden" id="email" name="email" value="<%= @email %>"/> 

    <input type="hidden" name="redirect" value="example.com/beta"; /> 

    <input type="submit" value="SUBMIT"/> 

</form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It can be solved by redirecting to another route. Currently, we render any view for a particular url. We have to use redirect instead of render. Also, we can pass query params while redirecting to transfer the data.

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

It's a limitation by rails. See this github issue for more details: https://github.com/turbolinks/turbolinks-classic/issues/22